# How can I get a substring between comma excluding inner parantheses string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get a string found between 2 comma.

For example, I want to split following input string into words/substring

input string :

```
"(ABC,pqr,xyz(I,j,k),lmn)";
```

Expected Output :

```
 1. ABC
 2. PQR
 3. XYZ(I,j,k)
 4. LMN
```

Comment: you have added `regex` tag, have you tried using it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`RegEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) with `,(?=[^\)]*(?:\(|$))`

**Explanation**

- `,` matches the character `,`
- Positive Lookahead `(?=[^\)]*(?:\(|$))`
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\)]*`

  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\)` matches the character `)` literally
- Non-capturing group `(?:\(|$)`

  - `\(` matches the character `(` literally
  - `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

**Example**

```
var input = "(ABC,pqr,xyz(I,j,k),lmn)";

var regex = new Regex(@",(?=[^\)]*(?:\(|$))");

// lets make easier on regex and just trim the outside parenthesis
var values = regex.Split(input.Trim(new[]{'(', ')'}));

foreach (var item in values)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
ABC
pqr
xyz(I,j,k)
lmn
```

---

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SeYxnS)

Comment: Thaks a lot @TheGeneral. This is really a good solution.